# JavaScript: generating HTML strings from a tree object with indentation

Tags: javascript, html

I needed to generate the HTML strings from a tree object with proper indentation. e.g.

```js
{
  children: [
    { tag: 'div', children: [{ tag: 'span', children: ['bar1', 'bar2'] }] },
    { tag: 'div', children: ['baz'] },
  ],
  tag: 'body',
}
```

would become

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <span>
            bar1
            bar2
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        baz
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my attempt

```js
function generateHTMLFrom(tree) {
  const recur = (node, depth = 0, indent = '  ') => {
    if (!node.children) return node
    return [
      `${indent.repeat(depth * 2)}`,
      `<${node.tag}>`,
      ...node.children.flatMap((child) => recur(child, depth + 1)),
      `${indent.repeat(depth * 2)}</${node.tag}>`,
    ]
  }

  return recur(tree).join('\n')
}
```

But the format is actually messed up because the indentation is all wrong

Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. I would recommend to take out complexity from your recursion to simplify it (no need, just for better readability).

Instead of multiplying `depth * 2`, you could initialize your argument with `indent = '    '`. And the first two lines of your returned array could combine in the way as you already did for the closing tag.

```
`${indent.repeat(depth)}<${node.tag}>`
```

And last but not least (your actual little mistake) the return value should not be node, it should be your node with an indentation:

```
return `${indent.repeat(depth)}${node}`;
```

You will end up with something like this:

```js
const tree = {
  tag: 'body',
  children: [ 
    { tag: 'div', children: [ { tag: 'span', children: [ 'bar1', 'bar2' ] } ] },
    { tag: 'div', children: [ 'baz' ]
    }
  ]
};

function generateHTML (tree) {
  const recur = (node, depth=0, indent='    ') => {
    if (!node.children) {
      return `${indent.repeat(depth)}${node}`;
    }
    return [
      `${indent.repeat(depth)}<${node.tag}>`,
      ...node.children.flatMap((child) => recur(child, depth + 1)),
      `${indent.repeat(depth)}</${node.tag}>`
    ];
  };
  return recur(tree).join('\n');
}

console.log(generateHTML(tree));
```